# Google Custom Search Engine how to show ads with JSON/atom API

Tags: adsense, google-custom-search

I am creating a search engine using Goolge Custom Search API (JSON/atom). I have associated my search engine with an adsense account but when I make queries I don't get any ads with search results also I have checked the Google Custom Search documentation and it does not mention anything about ads in the response of the API call, it only tell about the search results and the promotions.

I want to know if its possible to get search ads with JSON/atom API.

Thanks in advance,
Kamran